# Css3 Animation not Working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

```
@keyframes myfirst {
    from {background-position: 4951px 0px ;}
    to {background-position: 0px 0px ;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    from {background-position: 4951px 0px ;}
    to {background-position: 0px 0px ;}
}
@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    from {background-position: 4951px 0px ;}
    to {background-position: 0px 0px ;}
}
@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    from {background-position: 4951px 0px ;}
    to {background-position: 0px 0px ;}
}
body {
    background: url('http://parisparcoeur.ch/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Baord_Combo.jpg') repeat-x !important;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 80s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation: myfirst 80s infinite; 
    -moz-animation: myenter code herefirst 80s;
    background-size: auto 600px;
    min-height:960px;
}
```

So this is my code, it works great on chrome and safari, but it doesn't work on Firefox.

Url - http://parisparcoeur.ch/test/

Comment: Strange, I tried it out its actually not working even though "background-position" is a valid animation attribute (I have tested it out it worked on W3C On-line editor). Moreover if you add opacity or other parameter to the @keyframes declaration that is also getting executed that means the animation call is happening as expected. This would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looks like this could be causing the problem: The `@-moz-keyframes` rule is called `myfirst`, and you're calling `myenter` in the `-moz-animation` part. Maybe if you change that to `myfirst` then it will work? Also try changing `herefirst` to `infinity`.

Hope that helps :)

P.S. Not to do with your question, but the animation starts off fast, but by the end of the 80 seconds it's crawling along at a very slow pace. To stop that, add `linear` to your animation rule, like so: `-webkit-animation: myfirst 80s infinite linear;`. Then it'll all go at the same speed ;)